# Make an installer for python project

Tags: python, windows, open-source

I downloaded an open source project http://gmapcatcher.googlecode.com/files/GMapCatcher-0.7.2.0.tar.gz and I am trying to modify a few things in the code but don't know how to test the code! 
I tried to make an installer for the project but nothing worked till now maybe I didn't follow the right steps or I am missing somthing.

my question is how can I modify the code and test it ? and how can I make an installer for this project (I know there is an installer already in google but I want to make it myself).

Comment: "nothing worked till now"?  Is it installed?  Yes or no?  If it is not installed, then that's your question -- how to install -- everything else is junk, please remove it.  If it is installed, the rest of the question is very confusing.   You modify and test by modifying and testing.  What are you really asking?

Comment: what I am asking is : I have a python project (with no installers or exe files and the url in my question) , how can I modify a .py file and test the results ?

Comment: You modify a .py file by modifying it.  I don't get the question.  It's text.  Have you looked at it?  You test a Python project by either running tests or using it to see if it works.  I don't understand the question at all.  Are you confused by using a text editor?  Are you confused by the word 'test'?  Please **update** your question with some more information on what you've tried and specific things that you cannot do.

Comment: sorry for not being clear.I know how to modify a .py file but this project(please download it and take a look) contains a lot of files and I don't know which file I should run to run the entire project!..with visual studio all I need is to press F5 to run the project but here I just don't know how to run the entire project after modifying a file from this project.

Comment: @fadi: Sorry to make you work, but you have to read all the `.py` files.  What is this application?  Does it run on the desktop?  Is it a web application that runs on a web server under Apache?  Is it a library that you're supposed to use to create an application?  What is this GMapCatcher? Desktop Application?  Web Application?  Library?

Comment: @S.Lott : GmapCatcher is a Desktop application that allows you to view the google maps offline after downloading the maps.since I am a beginner in python my problem was how to build this project and run it on windows to see the changes I made with the code. thank you a lot for being patient with me ,I wasn't so clear cuz it is my first time with python :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the package has a `setup.py` for the use with [distutils](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html). The `setup.py` works kind of like Makefile for python. The way you use it is (in the directory where `setup.py` is located:

```
$ python setup.py command
```

Where "command" is... well... a command. Type

```
$ python setup.py --help
```

for more information. The two basic commands are `build` and `install`. `install` installs, as the name suggests, the package to your system. It is not probably going to do anything like create shortcuts on your desktop or anything like that. It simply installs the Python package into your Python installation. Judging by the contents of `setup.py`, it seems they're somehow using `py2exe` (google it; being a newbie I can only include one hyperlink in my answer) to prepare the Windows installer.

To simply run the software, however, it seems all you need to do is to unpack it and do

```
$ python maps.py
```

in the package's root directory - provided you have all the necessary dependencies already installed, of course.

Comment: thank you but what about the setup.bat and the setup.nsi in the installer folder how can I use them ?I installed NSIS and tried to Compile the setup.nsi file and I got an installer (exe file) but it was only 288KB and didn't seem to install any thing!